# Angular Material not generated to CSS when having dynamic CSS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, compilation, interpreter

So I'm having a problem with layout-fill angular material,
when I have a class which value took from controller

```
<div layout-fill layout="column" flex class="{{$ctrl.name}}">
```

in my HTML  theres no  class="layout-fill" 
but when I'm NOT adding class which is took value from controller,
theres a class="layout-fill"  in my HTML

anyone knows what happen?

Comment: so you want to assign class from controller variable to view right?

Comment: absolutely, but layout-fill not working if I do that